# Where should I get my Covid test (for travel to the UK) in India?

Tags: air-travel, india, covid-19

I am travelling from India to the UK on the 21st of January. The UK government has made it mandatory to get a negative Covid test before coming to the UK. Can I get the test done from anywhere or are there designated laboratories?

Comment: Have you checked the guidance here https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-testing-for-people-travelling-to-england?

Comment: @InSearchofanAnswer, And are you planning to come back to India?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.